# spring maven project： cause a BeanCreationException when autowire a property

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

application.xml

```
<bean id="setting" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:ftp/ftp.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:im/im.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="fileEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
</bean>
```

property

```
ftp_url = 192.168.1.136
ftp_port = 21
ftp_name = aloha
ftp_password = 123456
```

java

```
@Component("ftpConfigProperty")
public class FtpConfigProperty {
    @Value("#{setting.ftp_url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("#{setting.ftp_port}")
    private String port;

    @Value("#{setting.ftp_name}")
    private String name;

    @Value("#{setting.ftp_password}")
    private String password;

    //getter & setter
}

@Component("ftpUtil")
public class FtpUtil {
    @Autowired
    private FtpConfigProperty ftpConfigProperty;
}
```

Exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ftpConfigProperty': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.aloha.app.common.file.FtpConfigProperty.url; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'setting' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
```

I run a unit test then project throws this exception,but it didn't appear when i skipped test and compiled this maven project.Please help,thanks a lot.

Comment: what's setting? Is it just a property prefix?

Comment: setting is id of bean in spring-application.xml

Comment: What if you try referencing property names directly like "@Value("${ftp_name}")

Comment: SPeL is evaluating your expression -> #{ <expression string> }
Wrap you expression in quotes, making it literal.

Comment: its unused for changed # to @ and this @Value can jump to property file